# Should i expect a different GradCam heatmap for the same input image?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I'm trying to apply GradCam to my test set to get an idea of my model. The input is a 3D image_volume. I'm using a slightly modified version of the keras gradcam code from [here](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/).

I noticed that when I applied the "make_gradcad_heatmap" function (reproduced below) to the same image I would get different resultant heatmaps.

First the two main functions used are:

```
def make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index=None):
    # Generate class activation heatmap
    # First, we create a model that maps the input image to the activations
    # of the last conv layer as well as the output predictions
    grad_model = tf.keras.Model(
        [model.inputs], [model.get_layer(
            last_conv_layer_name).output, model.output]
    )

    # Then, we compute the gradient of the top predicted class for our input image
    # with respect to the activations of the last conv layer
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)
        if pred_index is None:
            pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
        class_channel = preds[:, pred_index]
        # print(class_channel)

    # This is the gradient of the output neuron (top predicted or chosen)
    # with regard to the output feature map of the last conv layer
    grads = tape.gradient(class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

    # This is a vector where each entry is the mean intensity of the gradient
    # over a specific feature map channel (equivalent to global average pooling)
    pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2, 3))

    # We multiply each channel in the feature map array
    # by 'how important this channel is' with regard to the top predicted class
    # then sum all the channels to obtain the heatmap class activation
    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output[0]
    heatmap = last_conv_layer_output @ pooled_grads[..., tf.newaxis]
    heatmap = tf.squeeze(heatmap)

    # For visualization purpose, we will also normalize the heatmap between 0 & 1
    # Notice that we clip the heatmap values, which is equivalent to applying ReLU
    heatmap = tf.maximum(heatmap, 0) / tf.math.reduce_max(heatmap)
    return heatmap.numpy()

def HeatmapGen(input_volume, model, last_conv_layer_name,pred_index = None):
    # Remove last layer's activation
    model.layers[-1].activation = None

    # Print what the top predicted class is
    img_array = np.expand_dims(input_volume, axis=0)

    # preds = model.predict(img_array)
    # print('Predicted:', preds[0])

    # Generate class activation heatmap
    heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, pred_index = pred_index)
    return heatmap
```

I ran the below code to see if I'm really getting different results. Turns out I am, but only 8 unique ones. It's always 8 unique results regardless if I change images in the non-cancer test set, or use different images in the cancer test set.

```
test_model = model
test_model.layers[-1].activation = None
for m in range(1):
    test_img = NonCanImageTest[m]
    img_array = np.expand_dims(test_img,axis = 0)
    num_test = 100
    heatmap_og = []
    heatmap_resize = []
    for k in range(num_test):
        # heatmap_og.append(HeatmapGen(np.expand_dims(test_img,axis = -1),model,last_conv_layer_name,pred_index = None))
        heatmap_og.append(make_gradcam_heatmap(img_array,test_model,last_conv_layer_name,pred_index = None))
        heatmap_resize.append(get_resized_heatmap(heatmap_og[-1],test_img.shape))
        # print(np.sum(heatmap_og[-1]))

    print(np.unique(np.array(heatmap_og),axis = 0).shape)
```

output:

```
(8, 19, 46, 30)
```

The model is:

```
Model: "CanNonCan_v1.0.1_Model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 InputLayer (InputLayer)     [(None, 45, 99, 67, 1)]   0         
                                                                 
 Flip3DLayer (Flip3D)        (None, 45, 99, 67, 1)     0         
                                                                 
 3DConv1 (Conv3D)            (None, 44, 98, 66, 8)     72        
                                                                 
 3DConv2 (Conv3D)            (None, 43, 97, 65, 8)     520       
                                                                 
 MaxPool1 (MaxPooling3D)     (None, 21, 48, 32, 8)     0         
                                                                 
 BatchNorm1 (BatchNormalizat  (None, 21, 48, 32, 8)    32        
 ion)                                                            
                                                                 
 3DConv3 (Conv3D)            (None, 20, 47, 31, 16)    1040      
                                                                 
 3DConv4 (Conv3D)            (None, 19, 46, 30, 16)    2064      
                                                                 
 MaxPool2 (MaxPooling3D)     (None, 9, 23, 15, 16)     0         
                                                                 
 BatchNorm2 (BatchNormalizat  (None, 9, 23, 15, 16)    64        
 ion)                                                            
                                                                 
 GlobalNorm1 (GlobalAverageP  (None, 16)               0         
 ooling3D)                                                       
                                                                 
 FC1 (Dense)                 (None, 50)                850       
                                                                 
 FC2 (Dense)                 (None, 50)                2550      
                                                                 
 Dropout1 (Dropout)          (None, 50)                0         
                                                                 
 Classifier (Dense)          (None, 1)                 51        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 7,243
Trainable params: 7,195
Non-trainable params: 48
_________________________________________________________________
```

I went through line by line and found that `last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)` changes each execution, though I'm unsure why it does so. I checked the outputs (last_conv_layer_output and preds) and found that these vary (again, 8 unique outputs each).

I ran the below code:

```
test_model = model
test_model.layers[-1].activation = None
test_img = NonCanImageTest[0]
img_array = np.expand_dims(test_img,axis = 0)
num_test = 10
last_conv_layer_output_list = []
preds_list = []
for k in range(num_test):
    grad_model = tf.keras.Model([test_model.inputs],[test_model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name).output,test_model.output])
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        last_conv_layer_output,preds = grad_model(img_array)
        last_conv_layer_output_list.append(last_conv_layer_output)
        preds_list.append(preds)

for k in range(num_test):
    print(preds_list[k])
```

and got

```
tf.Tensor([[-0.8683709]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[-0.72321826]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[-0.8572507]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[-0.78862524]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[-0.78862524]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[-0.8147389]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[-0.8683709]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[-0.69572026]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[-0.8849972]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
tf.Tensor([[-0.7177977]], shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)
```

I have a number of questions:

1. Should I get a single gradcam heatmap for each image?
2. Why does preds change on each for loop even though all the inputs remain the same (I believe*)
3. Why only 8 unqiue outputs? Why does that hold true regardless of input image?

Comment: With the same input, most models should have the same output in inference. Is the dropout layer a monte-carlo dropout (tured on in inference)? The `training` parameter while initializing this layer should be `True` in that case. What about the `last_conv_layer_output`, is it also the same? And what does the `Flip3DLayer` do?

Comment: Good catch on Flip3DLayer, that's the culprit I think. Keras doesn't natively have 3D preprocessing layers for augmentation I created my own (Flip3DLayer). It *should* only be active during training, but seems to get used when using grad_model. Since the layer randomly flips the image over the x,y, and z axis, with each flip being it's own .5 chance it results in eight unique images, hence the eight unique results for preds. It also explains the visual results i've seen, since they all looked like they *should* map onto original image, but were off by some translation (or in this case flip).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can add a `training=None` parameter for the custom layer call method, and then inside the method use an `if training=True:` block. `model.fit()` for example sets `training=True`, while e.g. `model.predict()` sets it to `False`.

Comment: Yep, thats what I had in my custom layer. I had to chang the line ```last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array)``` to ```last_conv_layer_output, preds = grad_model(img_array,training = False)``` and that fixed the problem. Thanks for the help!